# Getting 503 Service Unavailable on Codeigniter in Apache Server

Tags: php, performance, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working with Codeigniter 3 on an Apache server (XAMPP) and I have a problem on my live server (CentOS). When I try to load a new view, no problem occurs. But when I try to load a new view multiple times (like 5 times) before the old view finishes loading, the server crashes and gives me a 503 error.

We discovered this error when a user tried to use the navigation menu and seeing that the page was slow to load, because the database is slow, he quickly tried to load a new page.

This error occurs in all views, no matter how simple or complex they are.

Here is an example of a view that generate the error.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('example_model');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['information'] = $this->example_model->get_data();

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('body', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

In this example, the database function is a very simple Select query. I'm using Oracle SQL database.

I also tried to change the .htaccess file to allow more time to timeout server but that didn't work.

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have been looking for an answer for a long time, I will be very grateful for any help you can give me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to your code or htaccess as both look fine. Without any more information, my suggestion would be to check your Apache config (how many processes can it spawn, how much free resources your server has when it starts getting requests, etc). The Apache error log may also provide some useful insights. Having said that, this looks like something that could be better addressed in ServerFault

Comment: Did you get the answer?? because I am facing the same issue and stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't set the 503 HTTP Status using the redirect() function that CI provides. But you can set the 301 code (temporal redirection), which means that the search engine will know that your page is temporally redirected and it will not index the maintenance page.

[More info here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)